# How do you distribute beta iOS apps to your team without using test flight?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have build an app. i want to distribute it to lots of user until it get approved from Apple.

I don't want to use **test flight** and other third part distribution app

Is there is any way to do this

Thanks

Comment: you have an Enterprise Build or Development Build you want to distribute?

Comment: There are ways to do OTA of app. Refer different ways [here](https://longtrieuquang.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/how-to-distribute-your-ios-app-ota-with-enterprise-account/). More sites are listed [here](http://readwrite.com/2011/01/13/7-tools-for-ota-ios-beta-testing). You can also use [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) for direct ipa upload

Comment: I have developer licence for the same

Comment: You can create ipa using distribution profile, then you share it over mail, or any share medium. Generally I use dropbox . You can refer this link to share distribution ipa . http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html

Comment: @Sachin: Thanks a lot, seems it will work for me. Please put as answer. so i can accept. it might helpful for other users too

Comment: @HituBansal Now I have put this an answer please accecpt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create ipa using distribution profile, then you share it over mail, or any share medium. Generally I use dropbox. you can refer this link to share. http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.in/2011/06/distribute-your-iphoneipad-adhoc-builds.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alternate app distribution system such as [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/).

Is there a special reason you don't want to use TestFlight?

Comment: I dont want to use any app. i want user will get using direct link

Answer (score 0):

Try [diawi](http://www.diawi.com/)
Diawi is a tool for iOS developers to deploy Development and Ad hoc iOS applications directly to the device.
Source: Diawi

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of third party app distribution available over net.

You can use 
[Diwai](http://www.diawi.com/) , [Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) , but you have to make sure that user device id must be present in the provisioning profile from which you have made the build.

Comment: @hitu  through Hockey you have to upload the build over there server and registered user will get notification via mail that new build is available.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [Crashlytics Beta](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/), a Fabric product.

Answer (score 0):

Try [testFairy](http://www.testfairy.com), it is easy to use and will not require any app. Just upload your .ipa, inform your teammates and they will be able to install your app from the email sent (like the old testFlight).